# Some edits with thebibliography environment

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I'm finishing a work *(format: book)* and I wonder if there's any way to achieve this 3 requests with **thebibliography** environment:

1. Change name of section. As I include some webgraphy, I rather to show "Bibliography and webgraphy" instead that simply "Bibliography".
2. Make it appear at table of context with name changed. Even without name changed, it does not appear at ToC and not sure why (despite it appears as a new chapter at the end of the text).
3. Make 2 different sections inside it. My supervisor asks me to make a category for bibliography explicity used among the text and other one for recommended lectures.

Is this possible?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography and Webgraphy}` will probably change the title. You can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography and Webgraphy}` at the start to manually add to the toc. You could just issue another `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Recommended Lectures}` after the first `thebibliography` environment and then put in a second one, but you may want to tweak that, but it would be helpful to know what bibliography packages and tools you're using. Are you writing the environments manually or using BibTeX or something else?

Comment: @frabjous I'm using no extra packages but thebibliography environment. I've declared all bibliografy references manually at its section.

I will give it a try to those commands and see if that fits well. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @frabjous Comand `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography and Webgraphy}` works fine to make it appear at ToC with name changed, but it doesn't work to change name section and neither does `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography and Webgraphy}`. Must it go at some specific spot? I tried putting it before `\begin{document}` and inside thebibliografy environment, but didn't work.

Comment: Never mind, I tried `\renewcommand` just before thebibliography environment and worked.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be some flexibility in terms of where you put it--the preamble *should* work--but try it right *before* `\begin{thebibliography}` (not within). If it's still not working, I'd need to see a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to begin to guess why.

Comment: Oops, didn't see your new comment in time.